# Upload Progress Bar - Weird text remnant " ]]> "

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4

I am in the middle of creating a direct upload form for my rails 4 application. I have followed [this tutorial](http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and) and modified it to suit my needs. Everything has gone smoothly, except I am now receiving this weird text article after uploading a file " ]]>"

[image: song-uploads-screenshot]

Here are the relevant files:

**_upload_form.html.haml**

```
= s3_uploader_form callback_url: uploads_url,
  id: "s3_uploader",
  callback_param: "upload[direct_upload_url]",
  expiration: 24.hours.from_now.utc.iso8601,
  max_file_size: 100.megabytes do
  #file_field_container
    .wrapper
      = file_field_tag :file, multiple: true, class: "btn btn-primary"
    = button_tag "Select file", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'

  #uploads_container

%script#template-upload{type: "text/x-tmpl"}
  :cdata
    <div id="upload_{%=o.unique_id%}" class="upload">
    <h5>{%=o.name%}</h5>
    <div class="progress progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%">    </div></div>
    </div>
```

**uploads/create.js.erb**

```
<% if @upload.persisted? %>
  $('#upload_<%=params[:unique_id]%>').hide();
<% else %>
  $('#upload_<%=params[:unique_id]%> div.progress').removeClass('active progress-striped').addClass('progress-danger');
<% end %>
```

**uploads.js**

```
$(function() {
  $('#s3_uploader').S3Uploader(
    { 
      remove_completed_progress_bar: false,
      progress_bar_target: $('#uploads_container')
    }
  );
  $('#s3_uploader').bind('s3_upload_failed', function(e, content) {
    return alert(content.filename + ' failed to upload');
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for that string in your source code?

Comment: That looks like the closing part of a `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`

Comment: I have tried searching for that string, no avail. And Kevin, I am using a cdata filter in my haml (see _upload_form). Perhaps my syntax is off? I've googled haml+cdata, also to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up **converting the view to erb**. This cleared up the issue.

However, I am still wondering why it wouldn't work in haml...